# How to create falling eggs for my egg catcher game? New to object oriented programming c++

Tags: c++, class, loops, syntax

I've already managed to code a moving basket as well as collision detection, however I'm finding it difficult to print my eggs one by one. I'm new to objected oriented programming and I'm finding it difficult to manipulate classes as opposed to normal functions. What I'd like to happen is to have my eggs fall one by one as opposed to dropping altogether. 
Side Note: I'd like to add a buffer in between the egg spawns. How do I make that happen?

```
#define RIGHT  0
#define LEFT  1
#define number 10
int isalive = 0;
int score = 0;
int lives = 0;
int direction = 1;

class GameObject
{

public:
    int x, y;
    char symbol;
    virtual void draw() = 0;
};
class basket : public GameObject
{

public:  
    basket(char symbol, int x, int y)
    {
        this->symbol = symbol;
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    }
    void draw()
    {
        for (int z = 0; z < 5; z++)
        {
            gotoxy(x + z, y);
            cout << symbol;
        }
    }
    void movement()
    {
        if (_kbhit())
        {
            char ch = _getch();
            switch (ch)
            {
            case 'a':
                direction = RIGHT;
                break;
            case 'd':
                direction = LEFT;
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    void bounce()
    {
        switch (direction)
        {
        case RIGHT: x--;
            break;
        case LEFT: x++;
            break;
        }
        if (x >= 75)
        {
            direction = RIGHT;
        }
        if (x <= 0)
        {
            direction = LEFT;
        }
    }
};

class egg : public GameObject
{   
private:

public:     
    int isalive;
    egg(char symbol,int y)
    {
        this->symbol = symbol;
        this->y = y;

    }
    ~egg(){}
    void movement()
    {
        y++;
        if (y > 23)
        {
        /*y = 0;*/
        lives = lives +1;
        isalive = 0;
    }

}
    void draw()
    {

        {
        gotoxy(x, y);
        cout << symbol;
        gotoxy(0,2);
        cout<<"Broken Eggs:"<<lives;
        gotoxy(40,2);
        cout<<"Score:"<<score;
        }
    }
    void checkcollison(basket *basket)
    {

    if (x == basket->x && y == basket->y)
        {
            y = 0;
            score += 50;
            isalive = 0; 

        }
    }

};


int main()
{

    basket *f[4];
    egg *eggs[number];
        for (int z = 0; z < 4; z++)
        {
        f[z]= new basket('X', 38+z, 23);

        }
        for(int y = 0; y<number; y++)
        {
            eggs[y] = new egg('0',0);
        }

            while (true)
        {
            clrscr();

            for (int z = 0; z < number;z++)
            {
                 if (eggs[z]->isalive ==0)  
                 {
                    eggs[z]->x = rand() %40+20;
                    eggs[z]->isalive = 1;
                  }
                 if(eggs[z]->isalive !=0)
                 {
                    eggs[z]->draw();
                    eggs[z]->movement();
                 }

            }

            for (int z = 0; z != 4; z++)
            {
                f[z]-> draw();
                if(kbhit())f[z]->movement();
                f[z]->bounce();
            }

        Sleep(100);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can break out your for-loop once you have moved 1 egg.
In that case, once an egg has moved, you Sleep for 100ms.

eg.

```
for (int z = 0; z < number;z++)
{
    if (eggs[z]->isalive ==0)  
    {
        eggs[z]->x = rand() %40+20;
        eggs[z]->isalive = 1;
    }
    if(eggs[z]->isalive !=0)
    {
        eggs[z]->draw();
        eggs[z]->movement();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, when used in tandem with the code provided above it works seamlessly, however when I do implement it in my original code, i.e. one that involves a basket bouncing back and forth, score and lives, it seems to mess up completely. I know this may be asking much, but would it help you help me if I posted my complete code? I shied away from this originally as it may prove a headache for the more experienced programmers.

Comment: Post it, I'll take a look at it. (probably tomorrow)